# how to load some dlls over main dll in windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

i have strange question about windows service which is using a main DLL is name: Process.dll . Windows service call onstart():

```
Process client = new Process();

client.Method();
```

in this method Process.dll using another dlls. But windows service not finding a,b,c dll. Not Start up! Simple service is working fine but below architecture not working not atart windows service. Can you help me how to load another dlls.Or any solution? How to write codes according to below architecture? (a,b,c dll is static reference.)

[image]

Comment: How is Process.dll loading the a.dll, b.dll and c.dll? Are they statically referenced? Or loaded dynamically at runtime (in which case please show the code loading them)? Are all those assemblies present in the working folder of the Windows Service?

Comment: a,b,c dll is static reference.

Comment: create console application and call method in process.dll, you can debug and find what is the issue.

Comment: @Damith: everything is ok console or windows form. Not working windows service...

Comment: @Neros: i dont understand sorry :( ,

Comment: Are those DLL present in the same folder where is located the Windows Service DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("YourDLL.dll");

    Type t = a.GetType("YourType");

    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when trying to load files (whether config or DLLs) from a Windows service dynamically, is that you need to specify the location of the file to be loaded, even if it located in the same directory as the Service's EXE.

Here is a snippet I use to get the location of the Windows Service's directory dynamically from which you can then use the code snippet from ***aliboy38*** to load your DLL.

```
var exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

Assembly a = Assembly.LodFrom(Path.Combine(exePath, "YourDLL.dll"));

Type t = a.GetType("YourType");

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Hope this helps.